# Unable to clear the details when clicking the refresh button in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i'm trying to make a form which takes the basic inputs like contact number,name and email address.The idea is to get refreshed
"Return a fresh form" when the user clicks on the refresh button.Below mentioned are my requirements

Initally when the code is executed for the first time ..it the page loads taking the default values from the scope.As soon as i click the refresh button the form should turn fresh.However,the form is unable to load the default values  from the scope when it is executed intially.

Below posted is my code

```
 <div ng-app="ang2" ng-controller="form_controller">
 <form name="registration" novalidate>
 Name:<input type = "text" ng-model="name" name="name" required>
 Contact:<input type = "text" ng-model="contact" name="contact"required>
 Email-address: <input type = "text" ng-model="emailid"   
 name="emailid"required>
 <button ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <script>
  var ang2=angular.module("ang2",[]);
   ang2.controller('form_controller',function($scope){
   $scope.name='rishi';
   $scope.contact='4437577391';
   $scope.emailid='rishanthkanakadri@gmail.com';

   $scope.refresh=function(){

   $scope.name='';
   $scope.contact='';
   $scope.emailid='';
   }
  var stu= $scope.refresh();
  return stu;
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit of proper code inspection,I am able to come up with the solution.

```
$scope.refresh=function(){
$scope.name='';
$scope.contact='';
$scope.emailid='';
var stu= $scope.refresh();
return stu; 
}
});
```

Well,Earlier below part used to be outside of parenthesis

```
var stu= $scope.refresh();
return stu;
```

Now,I have kept it inside the paranthesis

Comment: You're assigning stu to itself- I don't think this is doing what you thing it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
var stu= $scope.refresh();
```

You are calling $scope.refresh by using the parentheses, thus clearing out your form.

It should be:

```
var stu= $scope.refresh;
```

Though I'm not sure what you're using stu for.